# Character encoding between Python2 and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, ipython

I have a string `x` defined as below

```
x = b'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'
```

In iPython2

```
In [10]: x
Out[10]: 'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'

In [11]: print(x)
LF                                                           � 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523

In [12]: x.decode('ISO-8859-1')
Out[12]: u'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'

In [13]: print(x.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
LF                                                           © 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523
```

Question 1: why is the output for **x** and **print(x)** different? The same between **x.decode('ISO-8859-1')** and **print(x.decode('ISO-8859-1'))**.

In iPython3

```
In [3]: x                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[3]: b'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'

In [4]: print(x)                                                                                                                                                                                    
b'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'

In [5]: x.decode('ISO-8859-1')                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[5]: 'LF                                                           © 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'

In [7]: print(x.decode('ISO-8859-1'))                                                                                                                                                               
LF                                                           © 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523
```

Question 2: As you can see, in Python3, the output for x and print(x) are the same. So are x.decode('ISO-8859-1') and print(x.decode('ISO-8859-1')). In Python2, it is not the case. Why is this distinction between Python2 and Python3?

Question 3: why the output of **print(x)** in Python 2 and 3 are different, the output of **x** is the same?

Question 4: why the output of **x.decode('ISO-8859-1')** in Python 2 and 3 are different, but print are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: why is the output for x and print(x) different?

Just typing `x` into a REPL can be thought of as:

```
>>> print repr(x)
'LF                                                           \xa9 2020 by S&P Global Inc.,200523\n'
```

> Question 2: As you can see, in Python3, the output for x and print(x) are the same. So are x.decode('ISO-8859-1') and print(x.decode('ISO-8859-1')). In Python2, it is not the case. Why is this distinction between Python2 and Python3?

Because `x` is a `bytes` object in Python 3, where `print()` will not attempt to decode the bytestring.  Python 3 [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) representation display binary values over 127 using the corresponding escape sequence.

> Question 3: why the output of print(x) in Python 2 and 3 are different, the output of x is the same?

Because `repr(x)` gives the same thing on Python 2 and 3.

> Question 4: why the output of x.decode('ISO-8859-1') in Python 2 and 3 are different, but print are the same?

Because `x.decode('ISO-8859-1')` in Python 2 produces a `unicode` object in Python 2 and a `str` object in Python 3, whose `__repr__()` differ in how they display non-ASCII.

---

If you want a more thorough read on all of this, check out [Unicode & Character Encodings in Python: A Painless Guide](https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/). (Disclosure: I wrote it.)